# Why is this contradictory clojure.core.logic/featurec result being returned?

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

...and how can I avoid it?

```
(run* [q]
   (featurec q {:a 1})
   (featurec q {:a 2})))
```

returns

```
((_0
  :-
  (clojure.core.logic/featurec _0 {:a 2})
  (clojure.core.logic/featurec _0 {:a 1})))
```

which I understand to mean that the `_0` map must contain at least the `:a 1` key-value pair AND the `:a 2` key-value pair. This seems contradictory as `:a` can't map to both `1` and `2` unless we used MultiMaps. I can't read it as `:a 1` OR `:a 2` because the constraints I specify are a conjunction. I would have imagined that the result should be `()` because the constraints are contradictory; there is no value for `q` that can satisfy these constraints.

I must be reading the result incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's contradictory. But it's what it is: There's no map that can unify with `{:a 1}` and `{:a 2}` at the same time.

`run*`, `all`, `fresh` all introduce a conjunction (AND) among its constraints. If you want a disjunction (OR) you could introduce a `conde`.

Perhaps your question is: Why core.logic isn't being able to "see" the contradiction and return an empty result set? I don't know exactly. But maybe it has to do with the fact that even if we remove one of the constraints, we don't get a "grounded" result:

```
(run* [q]
   (featurec q {:a 1}))

;=> ((_0 :- (clojure.core.logic/featurec _0 {:a 1})))
```

It reads as: anything, as far as it's a map which includes the `[:a 1]` entry. And I think that's the correct result.

Comment: Yes, my question is exactly as you said: "Why core.logic isn't being able to "see" the contradiction and return an empty result set?"

Comment: The result obtained from removing one of the constrains `{:a 2}` actually makes perfect sense to me; as you say, it's the correct result. Any map that contains the entry `{:a 2}` is a valid solution. This doesn't explain, however, why a contradiction is returned in the previous example.